# Module that provides Rules action to create node?

Tags: nodes, rules, actions

Is an Action to create a node available in any module? I tried searching but couldn't find it. I was hoping something as basic as a node create action would be available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Rules 2.x on Drupal 7, there is a "Create entity" action built-in to the Rules module itself.  You can use this action to create a node (Content), which is one type of entity.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me here! I'll try this out and I'll mark this as answered when I complete it. Or if anyone else tried it, let me know it works.

Comment: There it is! So it's hidden (and a lot of other stuff) under Entity all along! I must familiarize myself with this Entity module...

Comment: Rules might not be the best option for creating nodes as the selection of data for populating fields might be confusing. Better to just do it in code - see this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803597/how-to-make-a-new-node-with-rules-in-drupal-7