# Can I allow a user to create a Node using only an embeded rich text editor

Tags: 7, rules, nodes

In Drupal 7, I'd like to present the user with a single text box, that when submitted, creates a new node or entity.

I don't want them to have the standard node/add/type link and interface. Rather, I'd prefer a block that has a CKeditor and submit button. Upon submission, the content of this text box will become a new Node (or entity). The title will be auto-generated.

In some way I'm looking to replicate the functionality of Drupal 6's [Facebook-style Statuses (Microblog)](https://www.drupal.org/project/facebook_status) -- the same patterns now found on larger social sites: G+, Twitter, Facebook. However, instead of saving to a single database table, I'd like to Drupal to create a new node or entity from that content.

From comments below, I've been pointed towards [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules). However, I'm still having issue with how to go from submission of that single rich text area to triggering a Rule. Would the module [Rules Forms Support](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_forms) be of help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done this using:

- [Automatic Node Titles Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle)

> "auto_nodetitle" is a small and efficient module that allows hiding of
>   the content title field in the form. To prevent empty content title
>   fields one can configure it to generate the title by a given pattern.

- [Advanced Form Block Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/afb)

> Welcome to Advanced Form Block Module. With this module you can do the
>   following:
>
> 1) Create any number of blocks with a particular node edit form.
>
> 2) create any number of blocks with a particular node add form of a
>   content type.
>
> 3) Create as many blocks as you like of each kind.
>
> 4) From the content type choose which fields to display on a per block
>   basis.However required fields will be automatically displayed.
>
> 5) All forms will be saved through ajax. So multiple node forms can be
>   independently placed on a single page and worked with simultaneously.

With configuration and some css, you can get it looking really nice, and as a block it can go anywhere you want. You can also use hook_form_alter() on the appropriate form:

`$form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = 'BUTTON TEXT';`

to change the text of the submit button

Answer (score 1):

Seems like what you are asking for is a variation of the question in [Module that provides Rules action to create node?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/57909/module-that-provides-rules-action-to-create-node) . And the accepted answer in it, is also what I'd consider doing. I.e. use the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module to create such nodes ... Let me further extend this answer to add AbitMORE details on it ...

It isn't clear (yet) from the question how you would want to prezent that "single textbox" to the user. I see 2 possible approaches that you may want to consider to get a rule triggered:

1. Using [Field Collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection): that will make extra Rules events available like "after saving a new field collection" (or "updating an existing one", etc). So this could work if you think of a way to implement that text box as a field collection.
2. Using [Webform Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_rules): if it would be ok/possible to do so via a (tiny) webform somehow, then via the [Webform Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_rules) module you could add the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) integration with such Webform. That way you could "react" on such Webform submission using Rules. Because [Webform Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_rules) makes it possible to catch webform submissions by [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) and do whatever you'd like to do with it (that is: do whatever Rules let you do with it).

I'd try to go with approach '1.', if it doesn't work for you, then consider '2.'.

About using the [Rules Forms Support](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_forms) module: make sure to review the [Community documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1456178) about that module. It may help to actually "trigger" a rule. The step about "*Select the checkbox Enable event activation messages on forms*" in that documentation seems to be crucial to get the appropriate rules events that you might be looking for.

Comment: This makes sense. Would you have a suggestion for to trigger that Rule to execute? I'm having trouble connecting a textbox submission to a rule. Is there a handler to create a form that submits directly to a Rule? Upvote.